# Как пересоздать Activity чтобы сохранилось Bundle?

Tags: android

Я получаю в Activity некий Bundle.
В нем есть ключ Ice.

Я меняю значение Ice и после использую recreate(); Но результата не получаю.

Как сделать чтобы изменить значение в Bundle и пересоздать Activity?

Comment: Не очень понятно что выделаете. Вы сохраняете во внутреннем бандл активити и из него восстанавливаете? Или это у вас просто переменная какая-то?.. Раскройте подробнее что, куда и как сохраняете, как и откуда и когда восстанавливаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего метод `recreate` пересоздает активность при помощи старого intent

Можно написать свой метод recreate c преферансом и куртизанками

Например так:

```
@Override
public void recreate() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("ice", intent.getIntExtra("ice", 0) + 1);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```